# WooCommerce get list of all products returns double products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

At the moment I’m facing a problem with the List all products api call.
Currently I have 1045 products in the database. When I am trying to receive all my products in batches of 100 I don’t get the result I expected.

Result : 1045 products but I receive some double products ( same id and sku) . I checked in the database and there are no double products existing in the database. I have tried reducing the amount of product in the batch size, this won’t help either and I even get different results.

.../wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&page=1 => gives product with id 2988

.../wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&page=11 => also return product with id 2988

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try testing again by passing values for both `order` and `orderby` parameters.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran Thanks! I have tried including order and orderby with order = asc and orderby = id. Now I get the result I expected. Still I wonder why the result is strange without those parameters..

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well - it must be a bug! It also results in that sometimes you don't get all the products - I guess equivalent in number to the number of duplicate products... (WP 5.9, WC 6.2.0)

Comment: Thank you so much, Bug still persists in current version (WP 7.2.2).